# How to count the number of characters on each line in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

In vim, how can I count the number of characters on **each line**?

```
how
to
count
number
of characters?
```

For example, if I open a file with above text, I want to see counts like below

```
3
2
5
6
20
```

Comment: Is vim really a requirement here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
:for i in range(1, line('$')) | echo i . ': ' . strlen(getline(i)) | endfor
```

This version shows the line number before the character count.

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
:%!awk '{print length($0)}'
```

---

**UPDATE:** Even shorter (every keystroke counts!):

```
:%!awk '{print length}'
```

since I just now noticed that length defaults to entire line.

Comment: Seems to replace the current contents of vi. So you might potentially overwrite the original file contents.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Then, do this: `:%!tee >(awk '{print length($0)}')`. This keeps the text.

Comment: Pro tip: If you want to sort by line length, change it to `:%!awk '{print length " " $0}`, then do `:sort n`

Comment: Love this kind of answer.  Pure and perfect vim.

Answer (score 1):

The question was about vim, but just for comparison, here is how you can do that in Vedit:

```
Repeat(ALL) {
   EOL
   Num_Type(Cur_Col-1)
   Line(1, ERRBREAK)
}
```

or as one-liner:

```
Repeat(ALL){ EOL NT(CN-1) L(1, ERRBREAK) }
```